# change functionality of R package

Tags: r, package

I am trying to get my head around an R package. I installed it from github, worked with it. Also downloaded the ZIP-File from github which contains the files of the package. For experimental reasons I added some code in the files I downloaded.

Now I would like to see whether my changes do what they are supposed to do.

Is there an easy way to do this?
I would like to avoid creating a whole new package and installing it. 
Or is this the only way?

I had the idea to directly change the code in the package I installed (location received from the function `path.package()`). Unfortunately I cannot access the code there.

The tutorials I read were also not helpful.

I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: What is this mysterious package you speak of? Your question is fairly vague, and could probably be improved with more specific examples demonstrating your problem.

Comment: maybe `devtools::dev_mode` would be useful to you although you would still need to install the package to use it. unless you want to source every script that you need to make something run, then you wouldnt need to install it, just have all the objects in your workspace

Comment: @rawr Your hint with devtools::dev_mode seems lead to a solution. I will try it and report whether it solved my problem :)

Comment: @nrussell The package is from https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection There added some line of codes